# encodeAll method doesn't get called when composite component is placed inside a PrimeFaces p:dialog

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces, dialog, composite-component

I have tested Balusc's inputDate component: [Composite component with multiple input fields](http://balusc.blogspot.ro/2013/01/composite-component-with-multiple-input.html)  inside a PrimeFaces dialog. The `encodeAll` method is not called at all and the select boxes are not initialized. The composite component works fine when placed in a form as shown in the article.

Why `encodeAll` doesn't work inside a dialog and how can be fixed?

**EDIT 1**

I use Mojarra 2.1.13 and PrimeFaces 3.4.2.

**EDIT 2**
Here is a sample from my real project. I used your component to learn about composite components. I have a view accounts, with a datatable and a toolbar. Pressing Add should open a dialog with a custom wizard. The dialog has its own form, but the wizard is not displayed.

`accounts.xhtml`

```
<h:form id="form">
    <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/flows/accounts/accountsTable.xhtml" />    
</h:form>
<ui:include src="/WEB-INF/flows/accounts/mainDialog4.xhtml" />
```

`accountsTable.xhtml`

```
<p:dataTable id="accounts" ... />  

<p:toolbar>
    <p:toolbarGroup align="left">
        <p:commandButton value="Add"
            action="#{accountsBean.initializeEntity}"
            process="@this" update=":actionsDialog4"
            oncomplete="actionsDialogWidget4.show()">
            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{2}"
                target="#{accountsBean.operation}" />
            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="accountsBean"
                target="#{sessionScope.beanName}" />
        </p:commandButton>
    </p:toolbarGroup>
 </p:toolbar>
```

`mainDialog4.xhtml`

```
<p:dialog id="actionsDialog4" widgetVar="actionsDialogWidget4" dynamic="true"
    modal="true">       
    <h:form>
    <costom:actionWizard name="wizard" widgetVar="wiz" bean="#{accountsBean}" header="#{accountsBean.entityHeader}" />
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

Comment: Can't reproduce it with Mojarra 2.1.20 and PrimeFaces 3.5 on Tomcat 7.0.37. In future questions please please mention the exact library impl/versions used and include an [SSCCE](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info).

Comment: Added the library information.

Comment: Now yet the SSCCE. I at least can't reproduce it with this minimal snippet in `<h:body>`: `<p:button value="dialog" onclick="foo.show();return false;"/><p:dialog widgetVar="foo"><h:form><my:inputDate/></h:form></p:dialog>`

Comment: I have tested differently: `<h:form><p:commandButton process="@this" value="dialog" oncomplete="foo.show()" update="mainDialog"/><p:dialog id="mainDialog" widgetVar="foo"><my:inputDate/></p:dialog></h:form>`

Comment: This is invalid dialog syntax. A dialog should not be placed in any form, but have its own form.

Comment: You are right. That way it works. Please formulate an answer so I can mark it as the solution.

Comment: I couldn't answer because I couldn't explain the cause from top of head and didn't have the mood/time to run the debugger to figure it. It's not my style to post an answer without any technical explanation. A [second question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15613725/encodeall-not-called-on-a-composite-component-when-rendered-attribute-is-wrapp) on the same problem triggered me to run the debugger and look in PF source code. I found and understood the cause and therefore also the right solution, which is now answered below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by the PrimeFaces [`CoreRenderer`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.primefaces.org/org.primefaces/primefaces/3.3/org/primefaces/renderkit/CoreRenderer.java/) not calling `UIComponent#encodeAll()` in `renderChildren()` method, but `encodeBegin()`, `encodeChildren()` and `encodeEnd()` individually. So it will always fail when it's declared as direct child of a PrimeFaces component, but it will work when it's declared as direct child of a standard JSF component.

If you perform the job in `encodeBegin()` instead of `encodeAll()`, then it should work. I have updated the composite component article accordingly.

On an unrelated note, the `<p:dialog>` should have its own form.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but I ran into the same issue but now it's on `com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer#encodeRecursive`, and it appears in nested composite components. Same fix though.