# encodeAll() not called on a composite component when rendered attribute is wrapped

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, composite-component

When I do:

```
<h:form>
    <ui:repeat ...>
        <ui:fragment rendered="#{xyz.type eq 1}"
           <h:inputText value="#{xyz}"/>
        </ui:frament>

        <ui:fragment rendered="#{xyz.type eq 2}"
           <my:component value="#{xyz}"/>
        </ui:frament>
    <ui:repeat />
</h:form>
```

`encodeAll()` doesen't get called on `my:component` and subsequently the existing values are not shown.

If I do the following though

```
    <ui:repeat ...>
        <ui:fragment rendered="#{xyz.type eq 1}"
           <h:inputText value="#{xyz}"/>
        </ui:frament>

        <ui:fragment rendered="#{xyz.type eq 2}"
           <h:form>
               <my:component value="#{xyz}"/>
           </h:form>
        </ui:frament>
    <ui:repeat />
```

The latter example is useless of course, as I want to have dynamic inputs. Existing (default) components as datepicker, inputtext, ... function ok, it is only my component that doesnt show existing values (encodeAll not called).

I also tried h:datatable component instead of ui:repeat (not sure why though), with same results.

```
INFO: Initializing Mojarra 2.1.6 (SNAPSHOT 20111206) for context '/webclient'
INFO: Running on PrimeFaces 3.5
INFO: Running on PrimeFaces Extensions 0.6.3
```

Comment: Is it a custom component (Java) or a composite component (XHTML)? Your question title and question tags are contradicting each other. To know the difference, read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822000/when-to-use-uiinclude-tag-files-composite-components-and-or-custom-componen/6822269#6822269

Comment: It is a custom component http://balusc.blogspot.de/2013/01/composite-component-with-multiple-input.html - inspired by your code

Comment: That's not precisely a custom component, that's a composite component.

Comment: I posted an answer, but in the future, please provide a real SSCCE instead of a too oversimplified snippet which doesn't reproduce the problem at all when copy'n'paste'n'runned into a blank playground environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't reproduce your problem based on the given code, but I can reproduce it when I wrap it in a PrimeFaces component. E.g. when `<ui:fragment>` is replaced by `<p:panel>` (without `rendered`!). This is caused by the PrimeFaces `CoreRenderer` not calling `UIComponent#encodeAll()` in `renderChildren()` method, but `encodeBegin()`, `encodeChildren()` and `encodeEnd()` individually.

If you perform the job in `encodeBegin()` instead of `encodeAll()`, then it should work. I have updated my composite component article accordingly.

Comment: Thank you BalusC, you just saved my day.